# REST URL to dig into JSON objects

Tags: json, rest

I am writing a mobile client that consumes JSON data from a 3rd party server (one which I have no control on). The problem is when I do a get on the following URL

```
curl http://server.com/zm/api/events.json
```

It returns a big list of events structured like so:

```
"events": [
        {
            "Event": {
                "Id": "280",
                "MonitorId": "1",
                "Name": "Familyroom-280",
                "Cause": "Motion",
                "StartTime": "2015-04-12 06:54:43",
                "EndTime": "2015-04-12 06:55:27",
                "Width": "1280",
                "Height": "960",
                "Length": "44.24",
                "Frames": "74",
                "AlarmFrames": "23",
                "TotScore": "973",
                "AvgScore": "42",
                "MaxScore": "279",
                "Archived": "0",
                "Videoed": "0",
                "Uploaded": "0",
                "Emailed": "0",
                "Messaged": "0",
                "Executed": "0",
                "Notes": "Motion: mudroom door, study door"
            }
        }, //and many more such "Event" events inside the array
```

I'm new to JSON, but when I read up, its specification say the server MUST provide a mechanism to extract any sub object. So, for example, I want to construct a URL to ONLY retrieve events which have a MonitorId of 1

I've tried

```
curl http://server.com/zm/api/events/Event/MonitorId/1.json
curl http://server.com/zm/api/Event/MonitorId/1.json
curl http://server.com/zm/api/events.json?MonitorId="1"
curl http://server.com/zm/api/events.json?Event.MonitorId="1"
```

But I can't seem to get it right. Can someone advise what is the URL I need to construct to only return elements where MonitorId="1"?

thanks!

Comment: Where did you read that the server must provide a mechanism to extract any sub object?

Comment: Every site has it's own API. You have to read documentation from the `server.com` in order to know what is the correct url.

Comment: Oh gee. Sorry - I was reading http://jsonapi.org/format/ and I misread "A server MUST support fetching resource data for every URL provided" as "A server MUST support fetching resource data for every object provided"

Shucks. I thought this is like xpath and I can drill down to whatever level I want. The server implements its api using CakePHP

Comment: Does it help if you took a look at the Controller and Model for this events.json? They are at https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/blob/master/web/api/app/Controller/EventsController.php and https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/blob/master/web/api/app/Model/Event.php respectively. I see associations created but not sure how it maps to constructing a url.

The routes are at https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/blob/master/web/api/app/Config/routes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By REST you don't start to construct URLs. That's the responsibility of the server, if it does not provide hyperlinks with URLs (or URI templates), then we are not talking about REST.

Try a different response format, maybe there is HTML, ATOM, JSON-LD, HAL+JSON, etc... something which contains hyperlinks.

> I thought this is like xpath and I can drill down to whatever level I
>   want.

Most of REST services do not support custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ZoneMinder docs:
[Return a list of events for a specific monitor Id](https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#return-a-list-of-events-for-a-specific-monitor-id-5)

Example :

```
curl -XGET http://server.com/zm/api/events/index/MonitorId:1.json
```

Or you can just filter your JSON output with the `jq` command.

Example:

```
curl http://server.com/zm/api/events.json | jq '.events | map (.Event | select(.MonitorId==1))'
```